# Show that a $\mathbb{C}[x,y]$ subalgebra, on which two homomorphisms agree, is the entire algebra

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $a,b \in \mathbb{C}[x,y]$ be two polynomials with complex coefficients.

Let $f,g \colon \mathbb{C}[x,y] \to \mathbb{C}[x,y]$ be two $\mathbb{C}$-algebra homomorphisms, which agree on $a$ and $b$. I.e. $$f(a)=g(a)$$ and $$f(b)=g(b).$$ It follows that $f$ and $g$ agree on the subalgebra $\mathbb{C}[a,b] \subsetneq \mathbb{C}[x,y]$, which I assume to be a proper subalgebra.

Denote  $$S:= \{s \in \mathbb{C}[x,y] \,|\, f(s) = g(s) \}. $$
Observe that $S$ is a subalgebra, and that clearly
$$ \mathbb{C}[a,b] \subseteq S \subseteq \mathbb{C}[x,y].$$

**Question:**   Given that $$a_x b_y - a_y b_x =1,$$
(where $a_x$ denotes the partial derivative of $a$ w.r.t. $x$) show that $$S = \mathbb{C}[x,y].$$

Remark: I am not sure it's even true.

Comment: If it is not true, it will be difficult to find a counter example, since the notorious Jacobian conjecture implies it is true.